# Xcode 13.4.1 - 14.1 : Cycle inside "--"; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: xcode, swiftui

After making a GitHub repo and adding my code to my account my code now throws me an error, previous resolutions to the error include changing the sequence of the build phases in Xcode but I seem to have no luck, I also don't have a header phase in my build phases which rules out the older method, error below.

Showing Recent Messages

Prepare build
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Cycle inside Target.swift; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Target': CodeSign /Users/macbook/Desktop/target/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/target.app

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: /Users/name/Desktop/Target/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Target.app/_CodeSignature ->

Build failed    4/10/22, 10:12 PM    0.7 seconds

Comment: I fixed my issue by removing the target.app file from the "copy bundle resources" stage of the build phases of my app, don't know how it ended up there but I sorted it and worth something to try if your new to swift like me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

Goto Build Phase tab.
Drag /Embed App Extension' and place it below 'Run script'.

Run it gain.
If you're on Xcode 15

Answer (score -1):

> `First, open Xcode and click on the project. Then, navigate to the "Build Phases" tab. You can rearrange the items in the list below by dragging them. There may be elements in my added visuals that you don't have, but you can ignore them and arrange the common elements in the order shown in the visuals. Make sure that the Embed Foundation Extensions and Embed Pods Frameworks are positioned below "Bundle React Native code and images." it is also exist for Xcode 15.0`

[image]

Comment: Moving Embed Foundation Extensions above the [CP] phases worked for me. Thanks